# Neural network as a customised XC functional in PySCF?

Tags: density-functional-theory, python, machine-learning, pyscf, kohn-sham

I've been trying to implement neural network as a customised exchange-correlation functional in PySCF but with no success. Below is the example code for customised XC functional. Anyone has any idea how to do that?

```
from pyscf import gto
from pyscf import dft

mol = gto.M(
    atom='''
    O  0.   0.       0.
    H  0.   -0.757   0.587
    H  0.   0.757    0.587 ''',
    basis='ccpvdz')

# half-half exact exchange and GGA functional
hybrid_coeff = 0.5


def eval_xc(xc_code, rho, spin=0, relativity=0, deriv=1, verbose=None):
    # A fictitious XC functional to demonstrate the usage
    rho0, dx, dy, dz = rho[:4]
    gamma = (dx**2 + dy**2 + dz**2)
    exc = .01 * rho0**2 + .02 * (gamma+.001)**.5
    vrho = .01 * 2 * rho0
    vgamma = .02 * .5 * (gamma+.001)**(-.5)
    vlapl = None
    vtau = None
    vxc = (vrho, vgamma, vlapl, vtau)
    fxc = None  # 2nd order functional derivative
    kxc = None  # 3rd order functional derivative

    # Mix with existing functionals
    pbe_xc = dft.libxc.eval_xc('pbe,pbe', rho, spin, relativity, deriv,
                               verbose)
    exc += pbe_xc[0] * 0.5
    vrho += pbe_xc[1][0] * 0.5
    vgamma += pbe_xc[1][1] * 0.5
    return exc, vxc, fxc, kxc


mf = dft.RKS(mol)
mf = mf.define_xc_(eval_xc, 'GGA', hyb=hybrid_coeff)
mf.verbose = 4
mf.kernel()

# half exact exchange in which 40% of the exchange is computed with short
# range part of the range-separation Coulomb operator (omega = 0.8)
beta = 0.2
rsh_coeff = (0.8, hybrid_coeff-beta, beta)
mf = dft.RKS(mol)
mf = mf.define_xc_(eval_xc, 'GGA', rsh=rsh_coeff)
mf.verbose = 4
mf.kernel()
```

Answer (score 4):

This seems like too broad of a question to get a good answer here, in fact I think most of the fun of your project will be finding out the best way to do this. One good place to start is this paper:

> Kirkpatrick, James, Brendan McMorrow, David HP Turban, Alexander L. Gaunt, James S. Spencer, Alexander GDG Matthews, Annette Obika et al. "Pushing the frontiers of density functionals by solving the fractional electron problem." Science 374, no. 6573 (2021): 1385-1389.

And more importantly, the associated GitHub repository:

> https://github.com/deepmind/deepmind-research/tree/master/density_functional_approximation_dm21

In this paper, a deep neural network is interfaced with PySCF. You can even run the functional yourself using the repository. I think studying their code will give you the right direction.